# v-cloak doesn't hide components while loading page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I can't get v-cloak working in my app. As you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHnjA.gif) components are loaded before vue.js has finished loading (in this example I hit Reload a few times to highlight the issue).

My implementation:

```
<body>
<div id='myapp' v-cloak>
```

My CSS:

```
[v-cloak] {
display: none !important;
}
```

}

What I tried so far:

- Moving the style to bottom of CSS to prevent accidental overwriting.
- Adding !important to display:none to ensure execution.
- Adding v-cloak to the components that stuck out in the issue.

Nothing works. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your code only an example or did you add `v-cloak` to your root vue instance? If so, it behaves fine, since the root instance is loaded, which will trigger `v-cloak` to show the content. You should move `v-clock` as close as possible to the content, that you want to cloak

Comment: Problem is: There is no difference in the loading behavior if I put v-cloak directly in the div of a certain component, in the root or if I don't implement it at all. It all looks the same. It's as if v-cloak is completely ignored by vue.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just misunderstand what [v-cloak](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak) does:

> This directive will remain on the element until the associated Vue instance finishes compilation.

Important word here is **compilation** - this means it works only for in DOM templates which are compiled at runtime. It has nothing to do with component *loading* (some data to display for example)

If you were using Vue 3, there is special component for this called [suspense](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/suspense.html#suspense). In Vue 2 you must do it yourself with `v-if` or `v-show` ...ie hide or display your components depending on whether the data is already loaded or not. Or use a 3rd party solution as [Vue-Promised](https://github.com/posva/vue-promised)

Comment: Yes. I misunderstood the way v-cloak works. I will have to do a bit more research here. Thanks for the tip about vue-promised. I will have a look at it. Thanks!